Display html content set in WooCommerce product variation custom field when selected
How can I render HTML code in the Product Attributes Description in WordPress WooCommerce? Despite trying a custom plugin code, the HTML always displays as plain text in the Attribute Description field.
Custom Plugin code which i tested but not working.
The HTML always renders as plane text in the Attribute Description.
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Product Attribute Description
Description: Allows adding HTML descriptions to WooCommerce product attributes.
Version: 1.0
Author: Your Name
*/

// Adding the custom field to product attributes
add_action('woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'add_custom_attribute_description_field', 10, 3);
function add_custom_attribute_description_field($product, $loop, $variations) {
    $html_value = get_post_meta($product->get_id(), 'attribute_description', true);
    echo '<div class="form-row form-row-wide">';
    echo '<p class="form-field">';
    echo '<label for="attribute_description[' . $loop . ']">' . __('Attribute Description', 'woocommerce') . '</label>';
    echo '<textarea id="attribute_description[' . $loop . ']" name="attribute_description[' . $loop . ']" rows="5" cols="40" class="input-text">' . esc_textarea($html_value) . '</textarea>';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}

// Saving the custom field value
add_action('woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_custom_attribute_description_field', 10, 2);
function save_custom_attribute_description_field($post_id, $i) {
    if (isset($_POST['attribute_description'][$i])) {
        $allowed_html = array(
            'a' => array(
                'href' => array(),
                'title' => array(),
            ),
            'br' => array(),
            'strong' => array(),
            // Add more allowed tags as needed
        );
        $html_value = wp_kses($_POST['attribute_description'][$i], $allowed_html);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'attribute_description', $html_value);
    }
}

// Displaying the custom attribute description
add_filter('woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 'display_html_in_product_attributes', 10, 2);
function display_html_in_product_attributes($product_attributes, $product) {
    $html_value = get_post_meta($product->get_id(), 'attribute_description', true);
    if (!empty($html_value)) {
        $product_attributes['Custom Description'] = array(
            'label' => __('Description', 'woocommerce'),
            'value' => wp_kses_post($html_value) // Output sanitized HTML
        );
    }
    return $product_attributes;
}

Adding HTML to Attribute description:
[![Adding HTML to Attribute description][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/KPYHYjpG.png
Testing HTML description:


Update:

A temporary solution to make Custom Tab with Custom Attributes which supports HTML.
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Custom WooCommerce Tabs
 * Description: Adds custom tabs to WooCommerce products.
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Your Name
 */

// Exit if accessed directly
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit;
}

// Register the custom fields in the product edit page
function cwt_add_custom_fields() {
    global $post;

    if ($post->post_type !== 'product') {
        return;
    }

    echo '<div class="options_group">';
    
    // Custom Tab Title
    woocommerce_wp_text_input([
        'id' => 'custom_tab_title',
        'label' => __('Custom Tab Title', 'txtdomain'),
        'placeholder' => 'Enter custom tab title here',
        'desc_tip' => 'true',
        'description' => __('This title will appear as the tab heading.', 'txtdomain'),
    ]);

    // Custom Tab Content
    wp_editor(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_tab_content', true), 'custom_tab_content', []);
    
    echo '</div>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_after_attributes', 'cwt_add_custom_fields');

// Save the custom fields
function cwt_save_custom_fields($post_id) {
    $custom_tab_title = isset($_POST['custom_tab_title']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['custom_tab_title']) : '';
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_tab_title', $custom_tab_title);

    if (isset($_POST['custom_tab_content'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_tab_content', wp_kses_post($_POST['custom_tab_content']));
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'cwt_save_custom_fields');

// Add custom tabs to WooCommerce product pages
function cwt_add_custom_tab($tabs) {
    global $post;

    $custom_tab_title = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_tab_title', true);
    $custom_tab_content = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_tab_content', true);

    if (!empty($custom_tab_title)) {
        $tabs[sanitize_title($custom_tab_title)] = [
            'title' => $custom_tab_title,
            'callback' => function() use ($custom_tab_content) {
                echo $custom_tab_content;
            },
            'priority' => 10,
        ];
    }

    return $tabs;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_product_tabs', 'cwt_add_custom_tab');

Adding HTML to Custom Code Attributes:

Rendering HTML in Custom Code Attributes:


You are making a confusion for (local) custom product attributes (referring to your 1st screenshot): The value field is made to set values separated by a pipe character, but not a description (with HTML). And your code is adding a custom field to the product variations, not really usable as a product attribute description. Note that product variations of a variable product are a combination of product attribute(s) term(s) (set for variations). Try to better explain, in your question, what functionality you are trying to implement. What is the purpose?

@LoicTheAztec I want that description box to show an HTML data sheet, with rows/columns.

@LoicTheAztec In the screenshots i just show the problem, and by code i tried to add custom html field in attributes which is not working. and that "Test HTML" is not my custom attribute, i created it using the AddNew key when navigating to Attributes tab

@LoicTheAztec I am sorry , i thought You were asking if it is my Custom Attribute i made by code, yeah i created it visually pressing the AddNew button.  I thought i have to achieve it the other way around by creating my Custom Specifications and do my HTML stuff there if it is not possible to extend the Attribute Description box to support HTML

@LoicTheAztec Yes the data is unique and different for each selected product and i don't enabled any used for variations" option and don't know where can i enable or disable it

@LoicTheAztec Yes, only the data changes , products are Slings, each has different and unique g/p, tons Width, mm L (min), m etc, i want to wrap that data in the table so users can read it with comfort

@LoicTheAztec Ofcourse i am waiting :)

Sorry It was longer than expected… I have answered below…

You don't really need to set a custom attribute for that, as it seems that you want to display some different data for each product variation of a variable product.
So assuming that you have set a variable product, with some product variations, try the following code:
// Add a custom field to product variations
add_action('woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'add_attribute_description_field_to_variation', 10, 3);
function add_attribute_description_field_to_variation($loop, $variation_data, $variation) {
    $variation_obj = wc_get_product($variation->ID);

    woocommerce_wp_textarea_input( array(
        'id'            => "attr_description{$loop}",
        'name'          => "attr_description[{$loop}]",
        'wrapper_class' => 'form-row form-row-full',
        'label'         => __('Attribute Description', 'woocommerce'),
        'value'         => $variation_obj->get_meta('attr_description'),
    ) );
}

// Save the custom field for product variations
add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_variation_object', 'save_amazon_link_field_from_variations', 10, 2 );
function save_amazon_link_field_from_variations($variation, $i) {
    if ( isset($_POST['attr_description'][$i]) ) {
        $allowed_html = array(
            'a' => array(
                'href' => array(),
                'title' => array(),
                'style' => array(),
            ),
            'br' => array(),
            'p'  => array(),
            'strong' => array(),
            // Add more allowed tags as needed
        );
        $variation->update_meta_data('attr_description', wp_kses($_POST['attr_description'][$i], $allowed_html) );
    }
}

// Add a "Description" row to the product attributes table
add_filter('woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 'display_html_in_product_attributes', 10, 2);
function display_html_in_product_attributes($product_attributes, $product) {
    $product_attributes['custom-description'] = array(
        'label' => __('Description', 'woocommerce'),
        'value' => 'n/a', // Default displayed value, when no variation is selected
    );
    return $product_attributes;
}

// Add variation custom field data value to the variable product data form
add_action( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'add_variations_custom_field_value_to_variable_product_form', 10, 3 );
function add_variations_custom_field_value_to_variable_product_form( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    if ( $attr_description = $variation->get_meta('attr_description') ) {
        $variation_data['attr_description'] = $attr_description;
    }
    return  $variation_data;
}

// Javacript: Displays the selected variation related html data
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'display_selected_variation_attr_description_js', 15 );
function display_selected_variation_attr_description_js() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) : ?>
    <script>
    jQuery( function($){
        const targetSelector = '.woocommerce-product-attributes-item--custom-description > .woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value';

        if ( $(targetSelector).length ) {
            const htmlValue = $(targetSelector).html();

            $('form.cart').on('show_variation', function(event, data) {
                if ( data.attr_description ) {
                    $(targetSelector).html(data.attr_description);
                }
            }).on('hide_variation', function(){
                $(targetSelector).html(htmlValue);
            });
        }
    });
    </script>
    <?php endif;
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).
So in the admin for your variable product, go to the "variations" tab and click on "expand" link:

Then add the HTML content (limited to the allowed HTML tags defined) to each variation in "Attribute Description" textarea field:

Save changes.
Now, in the front end, different HTML data will be displayed for each selected variation:

If no variation is selected, the default value (defined in the function) will be displayed:

You could also add multiple custom fields displayed on multiple rows…
